# Unknown toughbook hard drive interface

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

Can you help me identify this hard drive connector? I need to mount a laptop drive onto a desktop, but I am not familiar with this laptop hard drive's physical connector.

[image: A photo of the connector is here at this link].

The drive is from a Panasonic CF-18, and the specifications are [in this pdf](ftp://ftp.panasonic.com/pub/panasonic/toughbook/specsheets/s_TB18.pdf) from Panasonic.  Unfortunately the Panasonic specs are not specific about the hard drive.

I just need some key words to get started in the right direction - is it a form of IDE drive, and if so what is it called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, that looks like a standard laptop optical port.

It looks like they are using a big chunky enclosure around a standard hard drive just to add sturdiness to the drive / so there is less chance of it coming loose if it is dropped.

From your picture, I would guess that if you undo the screws (below), and pull that board off (gently), you will have a very normal SATA interface, or at the very worse, a Micro Sata interface (or if the laptop is old, an IDE one) and may need to buy an adapter.

[image]

Whilst not the same, I would say it is just a mobile version of something like this:

[image]

I am not sure the "real" name, but, if anyone would ask me, I would call it an "in-line hard drive converter".

Many laptops out there have similar "go-betweens", the most common I see are Sony laptops with custom mounts over optical drives. Again, it is just a few screws and you can remove the mountings.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say, it looks to me to be a shock-mounting assembly with a simple connector converter, especially as you can just about see the brown ribbon cable as it goes into the enclosure.

Comment: http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=286847 and http://forum.notebookreview.com/panasonic/232533-help-new-hard-drive-cf-18-a.html confirm wil's answer - its a standard drive in a fancy quick release caddy

Comment: yep, that was it.  Underneath all that was a standard 40-pin IDE drive.  I had someone take the picture off-site, so I had no way of knowing what was underneath before I went on site.  Thanks!